# Call module dynamically using variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

Is it possible to call a module and it's function using variables?

I have a koa route:

```
import Router from 'koa-router';

import one from '../modules/one.js';
import two from '../modules/two.js';
import three from '../modules/three.js';

router.get('/api/:m/:f', async function get(ctx) {
    let { m, f } = ctx.request.params;

    //how to call module.function using m.f()
});
export default router.middleware();
```

`GET` would be called to `/api/one/add` which would trigger Module `one` and it's function `add`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something like that:

```
<code>const modules = {
  one: require('../modules/one'),
  two: require('../modules/two'),
  three: require('../modules/three')
}

router.get('/api/:m/:f', async function get(ctx) {
    let { m, f } = ctx.request.params;

    //how to call module.function using m.f()
    const module = modules[m];
    const fn = module[f];
    fn();
});
export default router.middleware();    
</code>
```

Comment: `require` shouldn’t work in an ES6 module. The OP’s imports are fine; they just need a `const modules = { one, two, three };`